# In Minitest, can I trigger on-page JS and analyse the result/response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, minitest

I hope my question makes sense to anyone out there. I feel a bit lost at the moment, probably due to some lack of background knowledge. I will try to make the question as specific and concrete as possible.

In a Minitest test, can I manually trigger JS Event-Listeners like a button with an on-click event, and then test for the expected behaviour? In general, how behaves Minitest differently concerning JS, and why? Where can I read some more about the interplay Minitest/JS?

```
$('#question').on('click', function() {
    resetFontSizeForQuestion();
    showAnswer();
    adjustSizeOfAnswer(front_size_string);
    n++;
});
```

I can't find any information on that topic. Am I totally off-track? Thx for helping out, really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need an integration test that uses [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) which runs a browser session for you (in the background, hidden by default) to process the HTML and JS.

You're able to interact with that browser session using the commands in your test, and then check the result of what happens, including the results of running JS.

These tests are slower than regular tests, so you should use them sparingly, but they're the only way to test/check things that depend on JS on your site.

Comment: So, mainly I need Capybara to provide the driver needed to run JS? I will have a look into Capybara, thank you.

Comment: You know, there's a better way to thank people here on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I know about that, but If I'd accept the answer now already, wouldn't it discourage people to maybe give me a more detailed answer? Don't get me wrong, I don't wanna be ungrateful, but I was hoping for more background information. If nobody else answers, then I will of course accept your answer.

Comment: First, I was talking about up-voting not accepting. Up-voting is the way to say thanks.  And honestly, no, generally if people know a better way they'll still post the answer, StackOverflow even rewards you with badges if a non-accepted answer gets more votes than an accepted one.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hints. Still have to find out about the details here on SO.

Comment: No problem, there's a lot of help available, this info is in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Welcome.